# How to apply Box-Cox transformation in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I have data of the form:

```
X   Y
3.53    0
4.93    50
5.53    60
6.21    70
7.37    80
9.98    90
16.56   100
```

And I want to find out n so that this can be fit to a function of the form:

[image]

I am trying to determine n by Box-Cox transformation. How can this be done in Python?

Answer (score 20):

I think you want [scipy.stats.boxcox](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.boxcox.html).

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

data = np.fromstring('3.53    0 4.93    50 5.53    60 6.21    70 7.37    80 9.98    90 16.56   100', sep=' ').reshape(7, 2)

stats.boxcox(data[0,])
(array([ 0.91024309,  1.06300488,  1.10938333,  1.15334193,  1.213348  ,
     1.30668122,  1.43178909]), -0.54874593147877893)
```

Answer (score 4):

Box-Cox of 1+x may be helpful in cases with zeros([boxcox1p](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.boxcox1p.html))

```
from scipy.special import boxcox1p
boxcox1p([0.01, 0.1], 0.25)
```

Answer (score 4):

For Box-Cox Transformation in Python you must follow below steps:-

```
from scipy.stats import boxcox
from scipy.special import inv_boxcox

y =[10,20,30,40,50]
y,fitted_lambda= boxcox(y,lmbda=None)
inv_boxcox(y,fitted_lambda)
```

in `scipy.special` package `box-cox` method is present but that expect `lambda` explicitly.Hence i used box-cox from `scipy.stats` and inv_box-cox from special as inv_boxcox not available in scipy.stats.

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1:**

This is your dataframe

```
    X       Y
0   3.53    0
1   4.93    50
2   5.53    60
3   6.21    70
4   7.37    80
5   9.98    90
6   16.56   100
```

Your data contains 0 hence you can go for [boxcox1p](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.boxcox1p.html)

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.special import boxcox1p
df.apply(lambda x: boxcox1p(x,0.25))
```

Output:

```
    X           Y
0   1.835587    0.000000
1   2.241999    6.689380
2   2.394230    7.178730
3   2.554564    7.611132
4   2.803640    8.000000
5   3.281328    8.354362
6   4.188250    8.680616
```

---

**Case 2:**

If you have data that does not contains 0 values then you can go for [boxcox](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.boxcox.html)

```
    X       Y
0   3.53    10
1   4.93    50
2   5.53    60
3   6.21    70
4   7.37    80
5   9.98    90
6   16.56   100
```

then

```
from scipy import stats
df.apply(lambda x: stats.boxcox(x)[0])
```

Output:

```
    X           Y
0   0.910243    16.561988
1   1.063005    157.733998
2   1.109383    202.939104
3   1.153342    251.083555
4   1.213348    301.896331
5   1.306681    355.163289
6   1.431789    410.710034
```